# Integrating Claims with Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp-classic, http-headers, claims-based-identity

I am in a bit of a bind. I have implemented an STS alongside my MVC app and it is working fine. However, I need to finish up integrating this SSO with my legacy classic ASP application. I was previously planning on using the Server Variable "Auth_User", but for some reason after I implemented claims this variable shows as blank on the ASP side. I can see this server variable in my MVC code but not in my ASP code.

Problem: I can't see the Auth_User server variable inside my ASP application that is hosted inside the same IIS site as my .NET and STS.

Also, I also found this [Example](http://www.datazx.cn/Forums/en-US/cc0a32b1-d5e0-4fdb-b369-a6215ca24b73/action?threadDisplayName=using-sts-wif-claims-based-in-php-wordpress-sites&forum=Geneva) but was unable to implement. About halfway down someone posted some code for a similar situation, but I still wasn't able to get it working.

I tried modifying the code to the following.

```
NameValueCollection nv = new NameValueCollection();
nv.Add("ClaimName", "ClaimName");
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add(nv);
```

I kept receiving the following error:

`[PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.]`

Thanks!

Comment: there is no such object as HttpContext in classic ASP, to manipulate headers you need to use [`Response.AddHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I assume I use the C# equivalent, "HttpResponse.AddHeader" and then read it in my asp?

Comment: maybe I don't understand you, what part is C# and what classic ASP?

Comment: I would like to see the Auth_User server variable inside my classic ASP application, but it is showing blank.

Comment: have you configured the web in your iis correctly? you will only see the Auth_User variable when Windows authentication is enabled and eny other authentication is disabled